# Encrypt PDFs In Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, encryption, ms-access-2000

My Access 2000 application is generating a PDF from a snapshot of a report using [**ReportToPDF**](http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm).

After I have the PDF file generated, I am converting it to binary and saving to MS SQL Server. I'm looking for a way to encrypt it before I save it to the server.

What are my options as far as encryption?

Comment: Use AES in either CBC mode with PKCS7 padding or in CTR mode (no padding required).  If you need to ensure it hasn't been altered then use HMAC as well.

Comment: Do you know of any source code I can use as an example?

Comment: What are you using?  Java and C# both have AES built in, and there is BouncyCastle as well.  Most systems will have an implementation of AES, it is very common.

Comment: Nevermind I found a demo here... http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=2389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a demo that shows how to use AES encryption for vba/vb6...  http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=2389